# How to properly address the pixels in a CVPixelBuffer?

Tags: ios, cvpixelbuffer, cmsamplebuffer

The short question is: What's the formula to address pixel values in a `CVPixelBuffer`?

I'm trying to convert a `CVPixelBuffer` in a flat byte array and noticed a few odd things: The `CVPixelBuffer` is obtained from a `CMSampleBuffer`. It's width and height are `852x640` pixels. In sum `545280` pixels, which would require `2181120` bytes considering `4` bytes per pixel.

Now the first odd thing is, that the same `CVPixelBuffer` returns `3456` bytes per row, which is enough space for `864` pixels. Where do those additional `12` pixels come from? If one row in the final image is only `852` pixel broad, but there are actually `864` pixels in a row of `CVPixelBuffer`, how do I know which bytes need to be copied? Or which of those bytes are unused? Btw, are they unused?

An other thing is the data size reported `CVPixelBuffers`, which is `2211848` bytes. Now if we multiply the `3456` bytes per row with `640` rows, we'll end up at `2211840` bytes. So again, we're left with `8` additional bytes. What's the matter of those `8` bytes? Are they unused? Are they at the end?

Any advice that sheds some light on that matter is welcome,
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, your CMSampleBuffer is padding each row to a multiple of 16 bytes so that it can efficiently sling data about with the processor's internal 128-bit wide registers.  That's my guess.  If you access the pixel data using its rowbytes parameter and (x,y) in the range of (0,0) to (851,639) you should never have an issue.